# Troubleshooting java.lang.NullPointerException in Android SDK tutorial exercise

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Currently I am going through a Sams learn Android SDK in 24 hours book and cannot get past the first hour because of the problems.

As I mentioned before, I have read all suggestions I could find on the gen folder error and I have done the clean without the build all, I have removed gen and then did a build all, I have  set the permissions on this folder to be NON read only and made sure that the version of SDK is ticked under the Java Build path option on the projects properties.

This is a clean install of eclipse and Androids SDK and I have followed the instructions carefully.

In addition to this, I find eclipse/Androids SDK unstable, for example, double clicking on the strings.xml causes eclipse to lock up and then I have to reboot or shutdown. As and when I do get to the Android Resources screen for the strings.xml I get this error:

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Please can someone help as I really want to learn this language but at the moment, not getting any further than hello world!!!.

---

Ryan thanks for your reply . When I first installed eclipse it was on 3.5. With the adk isn't this installed via the eclipse install new software option via the window menu in eclipse ?

The book is fairly current as it talks about 2.1 of Android and I have followed googles and the instructions from the book and see no differences . When I first installed this all I followed googles instructions and I hit the.java build issue and it locking up. I then decided to install it again from scratch and.following the book downloaded eclipse IDE java ee developers

To Mike - not that I have notice, you don' think it is a virus do you?

Latest on this matter - I have installed 3.5 non EE version and although I do not get the build errors anymore, I still find the eclipse interface to hang on occasions.

Comment: If you don't mind me asking is your computer just really slow?

Comment: If you have these issues, what version of eclipse + ADT are you using? I just setup a fresh build of eclipse 3.6 + ADT 0.9.7 and it is working without a hitch. What instructions are you following? maybe if you post that, we can tell you if something is wrong there. I can't see the book being that "current" when it comes to what version of eclipse+ADT it uses. not to mention what version of the SDK is installed. What version of the JDK do you have installed?

Comment: Ryan thanks for your reply . When I first installed eclipse it was on 3.5. With the adk isn't this installed via the eclipse install new software option via the window menu in eclipse ? 

The book is fairly current as it talks about 2.1 of Android and I have followed googles and the instructions from the book and see no differences . 

When I first installed this all I followed googles instructions and I hit the.java build issue and it locking up. I then decided to install it again from scratch and.following the book downloaded eclipse IDE java ee developers

Comment: To Mike - not that I have notice, you don' think it is a virus do you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem I have had with eclipse etc has been my A/V program  Kaspersky, since changing this I do not seem to be having any problems .

Thanks for everyones input on this.

Answer (score 1):

If you import a makefile projects directly, it will occur an error "NullPoint Exception", the proper way is:new a makefile project first,then copy your files into the newly created project. Build it.

Answer (score 0):

I've found when the gen folder can not build, it's a problem parsing strings. So you might want to right click on strings.xml and open that up using the plain text editor. If you're getting errors on a completely new app, then it might be something else, but I would at least check out strings.xml.

Comment: That allowed me to edit the xml but I then got an error trying to run the program. I have checked the syntax of what I have done and cannot see an issue.

I think I may try and install this on another machine but I really want this working on the one that is giving me problems.

Comment: Well I have just installed eclipse , the JDK , android SDK and the ADT again and still get the problem with the gen folder.

This is really bugging me now as I really want to learn this language and go through this book. Its clear that something is wrong as other people are able to use this environment.

Would it be possible for someone to post the steps they use to install it all? I have followed the steps by goggles SDK site but as I do not get any errors during the install I cannot see any problems.

Comment: update - installed eclipse 3.5 (started with this version and then tried 3.6) on the different machine , installed all of the other parts - working better on this machine, although I had to set the java build path to include the android sdk version and this stopped the build path (didn't work on the other PC) 

Going to do a clean install of the other PC (planned to do this anyway) and see if this makes a difference